# Output two distinct images to two different Video outputs display using OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to split an image into two, do some image processing on them, and send them to two different displays. Can I do that using OpenCV? If the answer is yes, how? A simple example will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Sure**, if you are using the C interface you need to create 2 windows:

```
cvNamedWindow("1st_window");
cvNamedWindow("2nd_window");
```

and then display the images you have on them:

```
cvShowImage("1st_window", image1);
cvShowImage("2nd_window", image2);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

The code above assumes `image1` and `image2` are valid `IplImage*` that could have been created with:

```
IplImage* image1 = cvLoadImage("image1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
IplImage* image2 = cvLoadImage("image2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: Thanks Karl for your response, but is this for two windows in the same video display monitor or is it to send to two video monitor? I want to send it to two different LCD monitor via two different video connector, forgive me if I was not clear.

Comment: I guess you can try calling [`cvMoveWindow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow) to place the window in a specific location of the screen, but moving a window to another display monitor is something that is done with the [OS API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7429596/176769).